# django how to display a weeks data

Tags: django, datetime, django-views, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

Hi thanks for helping me

I being doing some browsing on google and stack overflow, but documentation django and python I can hardly understand, how the they make code run

I just can't figure out a way to **display week data** (table & chart) with 
*two toggle button* to toggle different weeks of 53 weeks in a year

I had try using the week in Django template tags; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date
but I get empty value instead; here example I did `{{ value|date:"W" }}`

is there easily way to do this? I do not wish to use the weekarchiveview:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#weekarchiveview

As I need to toggle between years,months and weeks on same page.

Below are my codes

*this my code for views*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView ,TemplateView
from zigview.models import tank_system

from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date, timedelta    
class EC(ListView):
        model = tank_system
        template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/EC.html'
        ordering = ['-datetime']  # sort dates in descending order

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            return {'tank': self.get_queryset()}
```

This is my apps url codes

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views #function views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required

urlpatterns = [

    path('',login_required(views.index.as_view()), name='index'), # views to call our index
    path(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name = 'myapp'), # tell django the which path to our main page
    path(r'liveSterm/', login_required(views.Strem), name='Livesterm'), #call live strem page
    path(r'EC-data/', login_required(views.EC.as_view()), name='EC'),
    path(r'ph-data/', login_required(views.ph.as_view()), name='ph'),
    path(r'Water-Temptures/', login_required(views.WT.as_view()), name='WT'),
    path(r'Room-Temptures/', login_required(views.RT.as_view()), name= 'RT'),
    path(r'Water-Flow-IN/', login_required(views.WaterFlowIN.as_view()), name= 'WFI'),
    path(r'Water-Flow-OUT/', login_required(views.WaterFlowOUT.as_view()), name= 'WFO'),
    ]
```

this is my models codes

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from decimal import Decimal
# having errors KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"

class tank_system(models.Model):

    PH = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    EC = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    Winlet = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    Woutlet = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    WaterLevel = models.IntegerField(default=500)
    TempWater = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    TempRoom = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    tanks = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 'value' in your context. The context is only 'tank'. So to get the datetime you can use `{{ tank.datetime|date:"W" }}`

To switch after clicking on a button you can write a simple piece of javascript that changes the inner html of a certain part of your DOM to `{{ tank.datetime|date:"W" }}` ,  `{{ tank.datetime|date:"M" }}` etc. after clicking the button

Comment: Dear Roy I had tried that {{ tank_system.datetime|date:"W" }}, it give a value of 50 for all my column not the value of 7 days, if I would to use {{ tank.datetime|date:"W" }} I be calling my list instead :(. But appreciate you trying to help; thank you

Comment: Since a datetime only has 1 value you're not getting 7 values, date:"W" does give you the week number, if you want to have the days of that week, there might be a library for that or you can implement it yourself with some date logic.

Comment: I'm sorry Roy; what do you mean, "datetime only has  had 1 value" didn't the "week" column, or i'm making it read rows? and no i'm not looking for a day, 
but a weeks. But thank you for your help

Comment: Once you give a tank datetime a value, you'll give it 1 datetime (so e.g. 14 december 2018 09:23), i'm unsure how you want to get multiple weeks out of that 1 value

Comment: Hmm after reading documentary of django 10 times i think i'm starting understand what mean you Roy. thank you